# PROC EXPORT sas Data Files (v7 Long Name) (*.sas7bdat) to Library

Tags: sas

Using PROC SQL I need to export a file in .sas7bdat format to a library. I can not export the file to my local machine. Using PROC EXPORT no DBMS option works.

Is exporting in this file type possible to my network library?

Thank you

Comment: You do not need to "export" a SAS dataset. You just create it.  Are you asking how to move a file from your SAS server to some other server?  Can you see the network folder from your SAS code?  Can you use FTP or SFTP to connect to your target folder?

Comment: What sort of error message you get? With me, the usual error is mistyping of the output destination. This works with me: **   proc export data=my_data
            OUTFILE= "\\Networ_drive\My_folder\My_output.txt"
            DBMS=TAB REPLACE; run;**

Comment: Tom you are correct. Thank you for the advice. Worked perfectly. Thank you.